# Msbuild commandline publishing a web site, not web app

Tags: msbuild

This is the bat file. How do you specify the output directory? Is it a bat switch, or in the .publishproj? It builds, but am not sure how to create, or find, the output files! (C:\Publish is empty)

"MSBuild.exe" C:\Temp2\PGRWebAdmin\website.publishproj /fl /p:PublishProfile=Publish /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0 "/v:diag" /p:OutDir="C:\Publish"

Answer (score 0):

Got there in the end: /p:DeployOnBuild=true